# ef core 6/mysql performance issue

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, entity-framework

I am having a strange performance issue with ef core 6 and MySlq and hoping you can help me spot the problem.
here's my setup.

1. Ef core 6/ Mysql
2. Table per Hierarchy approach. Here's the hierarchy:

   ```
   public class RealEstate : Property{
   }
   ```
3. Repository pattern with UnitOfWork. Here it is:

   ```
   public interface IUnitOfWork 
   {  
       IDataAccessLayer<Property> PropertyRepository { get; }
       IDataAccessLayer<RealEstate> RealEstateRepository { get; }
   }
   ```
4. Here's my database context:

   ```
   public class MeerkatContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
   {
       public MeerkatContext(DbContextOptions<MeerkatContext> options) : base(options)
       {
       }

       public DbSet<Property> Property { get; set; }
       public DbSet<RealEstate> RealEstate { get; set; }
   }
   ```
5. I have the following index defined on the "property" table

[image]

6. I have 1 million records in the table.

Here's the issue:

The following query take less than 1 seconds:

```
var count1 = await this._unitOfWork.PropertyRepository.CountAsync(x =>
    x.CountryId == 1 && !x.IsBlocked && x.IsPublic);
```

this one takes 10 seconds:

```
var count2 = await this._unitOfWork.RealEstateRepository.CountAsync(x =>
     x.CountryId == 1 && !x.IsBlocked && x.IsPublic);
```

I am stomped. Any help would be really appreciated.

edited to show query excution in MySql WorkBench

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you compared number of items in tables? Have you compared generated sql (JIC)? Have you compared query plans? Why do you think that similar query to two different tables should have the same running time?

Comment: Hi Guru Stron,  thanks for the reply.  The table is the same. "Table per Hierarchy" in entity framework means that all classes in the hierarchy are saved in the same table.  There is a discriminator column to differentiate them

Comment: This seems a bit odd. Normally with TPH and a discriminator you'd have an abstract class "Property" with two or more inheriting classes, I.e. "RealEstate" and "Commercial" etc.  The DbContext would normally not have a Property DbSet. Regarding performance when querying against the subclass entity: You would want to check that your Discriminator column is indexed, ideally including the PK.

Comment: Hi Steve, you were right about my inheritance hierarchy being off.  I fixed it with this tutorial  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance.  However  the performance remains unchanged.  I noticed that the two queries generate different sql statements.  The "Where" clauses are different. Here's the first:   WHERE ((`p`.`CountryId` = 1) AND NOT (`p`.`IsBlocked`)) AND `p`.`IsPublic`       and here is the second:   WHERE (`p`.`CategoryName` = 'RealEstate') AND (((`p`.`CountryId` = 1) AND NOT (`p`.`IsBlocked`)) AND `p`.`IsPublic`)

Comment: I updated the original post to include a picture  the query execution from MySql WorkBench.  Despite the existence of an index, it looks like the table is being scanned for the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Sind you probably want to search for un-blocked items, change the logic to help with the SQL:

```
AND NOT IsBlocked -- inefficient
AND IsBlocked = 0 -- efficient (using "=" instead of "NOT")
AND NotBlocked -- efficient (flip the name and logic)
```

In general: avoid `OR` and `NOT` when constructing SQL.  (This is an oversimplification.)

Then add this 4-column index to the table:

```
INDEX(CountryId, IsBlocked [or NotBlocked], IsPublic, CategoryName)
```

Look through the rest of the schema for similar changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply James.  the negation in the where clause definitely slows the query down.  Everything seems to slow it down really...even a join.   I might have to use a stored procedure instead.  The amount of possible filters is great so this is going to be tedious

Comment: When having lots of _possible_ things in the `WHERE` clause, I like to construct it on the fly, being sure to leave out anything that the user did not specify.  A Stored Proc is likely to be simply too messy to write; it's easier in PHP (etc).